# sending POST request to API endpoint to receive stripe_user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, stripe-payments

After a user signs up for a [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts#complete-express-connection) account with my app, they are redirected to my localhost, and an `authorization_code` is added to the url. I am then supposed to make a POST request with my `client_secret` and `authorization_code` to their API endpoint. The code provided by the docs says to do something like this:

```
curl https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token \
 -d client_secret=blahblah \
 -d code="{AUTHORIZATION_CODE}" \
 -d grant_type=authorization_code
```

But...where do I do this, exactly? In the controller? Like this?

```
def post_to_endpoint(endpoint)
 require 'json'

 begin
  uri = URI.parse(endpoint)

  post_params = {
    client_secret: "client_secret",
    code: "{AUTHORIZATION_CODE}",
    grant_type: authorization_code
  }

  req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
  req.body = JSON.generate(post_params)
  req["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  response = http.start { |htt| htt.request(req) }
 rescue => e
  puts "failed #{e}"
 end
end
```

The user gets redirected to a GET route on my app at the end of step 3, and then my app is supposed to make a POST to the Stripe endpoint. Do I need to set up a route? Can I have this action happen in the background?

Comment: hey @sabaeus - Im stuck on this part right now lol. Im using Node.js with firebase cloud functions, and running on an iOS device.. was this piece of code supposed to be ran server side ? or on the client ? I'm guessing server side because it has a secret key involved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution! write it as a module. it doesn't need to be persisted to the db. also helpful was using the [stripe ruby library](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/stripe/Stripe/OAuth)

i wrote a stripe_oauth.rb that looks like this:

```
module StripeOauth
 def self.connect(code)
  Stripe.api_key = ENV["STRIPE_SECRET_KEY"]
  Stripe::OAuth.token( {code: code, grant_type: "authorization_code" } )
 end
end
```

and then i called that from the controller action Stripe redirected me to:

```
def welcome
 StripeOauth.connect(params[:code])
end
```

`params[:code]` is sent along as part of the url, so

Comment: hey @sabaeus - Im stuck on this part right now lol. Im using Node.js with firebase cloud functions, and running on an iOS device.. was this piece of code supposed to be ran server side ? or on the client ? I'm guessing server side because it has a secret key involved.

Comment: @CodingwhileLoading yes, server side! it also doesn't *need* to be a module. i could've just put `Stripe::OAuth.token( {code: code, grant_type: "authorization_code" } )` in the controller, but i wanted it be its own thing

Answer (score 1):

The call to `/oauth/token` is something you make on the backend/controller to get an authorization token from Stripe that you'll need in order to make call on behalf of the connected account. Your user doesn't need to be involved at all with that call once they've authorized your platform to connect to their account.

Since you're using Ruby, I'd recommend using [stripe-ruby](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby) (the official library). That has [built-in methods](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/stripe/Stripe/OAuth) for using Oauth with Stripe Connect.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm using the official library. I'm afraid that what I'm asking is for an understanding of basics. My user is redirected to `onboard/welcome` on my app after they authorize my platform to connect to their account. Where I am lost is in how to make that call to `oauth/token`. How to i make a POST request in the background of a GET page?

Comment: Not a problem! There's a good example of how to do it [here](https://gist.github.com/amfeng/2314782). Specifically on line 39 of server.rb in that gist.

Comment: Afraid I'm still a bit confused :/ I don't need to make a get request to oauth/callback to get the authorization code, i need to make a post request to oauth/token with that authorization code I got at the end of Step 3 in the Stripe docs. I already have the auth code, what i don't understand is how to send it to the endpoint to receive my stripe_user_id. And would this go into a controller action? Or a model?